# Form Onclick with Required field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have currently a form which has the below code, the issue is that when a user presses the form submit button even if not checking the required field the `onclick` call is still triggered, how can I make it so that you HAVE to fulfill the *required field* before getting a trigger?

```html
<form method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
 <select id="inputState" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">
  <option>10,000 credits</option>
  <option>25,000 credits</option>
  <option>50,000 credits</option>
  <option>75,000 credits</option>
  <option>100,000 credits</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 <div class="text-center">
 <div class="row justify-content-center mb-2">
 <div class="col-12 col-md-8 text-center">
 <p class="mb-0 small text-muted"><strong>Promotion Disclaimer</strong>
 <br>You will be required to install a free mobile app from our sponsors to receive your Coins for free. This process only takes a minute or two and you can remove the app once you're finished.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-check">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1" required>
   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
  I agree to Promotion Disclaimer
   </label>
 </div>
 <br>
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-continue" data-step="3" onclick="call_locker();">Continue</button>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: The [default behavior of a button in a form is to attempt to submit that form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type).  You might wish to capture the event with a handler and put in place an [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) unless you can verify the form is valid.

Comment: Just to clarify @AlexanderNied, the default behavior of a button is to attempt to submit ONLY if you have the `type="submit"` on it. You can still have buttons in a form that will NOT attempt to submit it.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro - Sorry, I mischaracterized this somewhat-- I called it the "default behavior" because if no `type` or an empty `type` attribute is included on the `<button>` then it will behave as a `type="submit"`.  But you are correct-- the way I typed it is somewhat unclear/misleading-- if a specific, non-"submit" `type` attribute is included on the `<button>` it will _not_ attempt to submit the form when clicked.

Answer (score 5):

Using the form `onsubmit` event, move your call_locker call into the `form` element. This is called when there is a `submit` event. You can trigger said event by default on your button click. To prevent the refreshing of the page, you can either add `event.preventDefault()` or returning false from the function. Here I have a mock function of `call_locker` which returns false.

```html
<script>
call_locker = () => { console.log('called locker'); return false; }
</script>

<form method="post" onsubmit="return call_locker();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="inputState" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">
      <option>10,000 credits</option>
      <option>25,000 credits</option>
      <option>50,000 credits</option>
      <option>75,000 credits</option>
      <option>100,000 credits</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-2">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 text-center">
        <p class="mb-0 small text-muted"><strong>Promotion Disclaimer</strong>
          <br>You will be required to install a free mobile app from our sponsors to receive your Coins for free. This process only takes a minute or two and you can remove the app once you're finished.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
  I agree to Promotion Disclaimer
   </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-continue" data-step="3">Continue</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution to your issue.

Instead of using the `onclick` event, you can use the `onsubmit` event, which will not call the function unless the form is submitted.

The browser will not submit the form if elements with the `required` attribute are not filled out, so the function will not be called if you are using the `onsubmit` event until the `required` fields are filled out.

`onclick="call_locker();"` should become `onsubmit="call_locker();"`

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve your problem.
if you want to make it so that the browser won't refresh itself *(and therefore submit the form)* whenever you click on the submit button and your fields are not fulfilled, you can make your javascript code do it by **preventing the default** of the submit key which is refreshing the browser whenever it is pressed.

**Javascript Example**

```
call_locker(event)
{
  if (document.getElementById().value === undefined && 
      document.getElementById(defaultCheck1).value === undefined)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```